# TypeScript, Apollo GraphQL yield not assignable" error for node-fetch

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm working on implementing [schema stitching](https://graphql-tools-fork.netlify.com/docs/graphql-tools-fork/schema-stitching/) in a NodeJS/Apollo/GraphQL project I'm working on.  It's written in TypeScript.

The code is

```
import {
    makeRemoteExecutableSchema,
    introspectSchema,
    mergeSchemas
} from 'graphql-tools';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';


export default  async () => {
    const link = new HttpLink({
        uri:'http://localhost:4545',
        fetch
    })
    const remoteSchema = await introspectSchema(link);
    // Make remote executable schema
    return makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
        schema: remoteSchema,
        link
    });

}
```

and it's complaining that

[image].

The referenced section of the types file is

```
export interface HttpOptions {
    uri?: string | UriFunction;
    includeExtensions?: boolean;
    fetch?: WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope['fetch'];
    headers?: any;
    credentials?: string;
    fetchOptions?: any;
}
```

This seems to be a [bug that has been fixed](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/1131), but it doesn't seem fixed here, although I'm using the latest versions and the line

`fetch?: WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope['fetch'];`

does seem to be what is recommended for one of the workarounds, hence, it should be fixed.

For what it's worth, my `package.json` is

```
{
  "dependencies": {

    "apollo-datasource-graphql": "^1.3.2",
    "apollo-datasource-rest": "^0.7.0",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.16",
    "apollo-server": "^2.10.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.7",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "uuid": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.26.43",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "pino": "^5.16.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc && node dist/index.js"
  }
}
```

Any clues much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using [cross-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch) will solve the issue.

Comment: What is the difference between 'cross-fetch' and 'node-fetch' in this context?  (It will all be on the server here)